# Hide/change part of the URL using a filter

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to hide (or exchange for a generic string) a sensitive part of the url in my web application.

I want to be able to translate between two strings `foo` and `bar` where `foo` is the original value in the url and `bar` is the one that should be visible to the user. But my MVC app should still effectively get `foo`.

From what I understand this should be possible with Plays filters. However I am really struggling to wrap my head around this.

What I have tried so far is:

```
class Anonymizer @Inject()(implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: 
ExecutionContext) extends Filter {
 def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
       (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
  if (requestHeader.uri.matches(".*foo")) {
    val anon: String = requestHeader.uri.replace("foo", "bar")
    result.withHeaders("Location" -> anon)
  }
  else result
  }
  }
}
```

This manages to change `foo` to `bar` in browser, however the application fails, since it gets `bar` now. I am now stuck at converting back to `foo` for the application logic but still having `bar` in the URL.

Comment: Instead of passing this in the URL, you could encrypt it and pass it in a Cookie or Flash or Session or something like that. Alternatively, just encrypt it before passing it into the URL and decrypt it in the next route.

Comment: What does your URL look like? Is this thing you want to hide a query parameter, or is it actually part of the URL path (ie is it more like `http://example.com/foo/XXX` or `http://example.com?foo=XXX`)?

Comment: It is a profile name variable that changes with selection and is used to dynamicaly generate pages. So it is a query parameter.

Comment: In that case, any of the above suggestions will work just fine. In order to encrypt, something like this: https://gist.github.com/alexandru/ac1c01168710786b54b0 will be a good place to start, although if you want something _really_ encrypted I think that's well out of scope of a simple Q&A question. :P

Comment: I just realised I got query parameter and URL path the wrong way around in my previous comment. Either way, if your thing is more like `?foo=XXX`, any of the above suggestions will work fine.

Comment: Thank you, will check it out right away although encryption is actually not really what I am looking for, more like using a list of aliases, more like using alias for just one concrete profile. That is why i did not want to use encryption for all of them as its unecessary. Seems I did not quite understand what the filters are capable of and I will have to change change my code more extensively.

Comment: Ah fair enough. You could always use something like a Map to store a name and its corresponding obfuscated value, or if you're running a database keep track of which fake value corresponds to which real value (either in a new table column or a new field depending on if your DB is relational or not).